# IE 10 is not showing modals. Seems like it's an issue with jQuery 1.7.1's animate

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

If you go to [www.carsense.com](http://www.carsense.com), and click the login link in the upper-right corner:

[image]

You can see that the curtain shows, but the actual modal does not, although it is there:

[image]

If you find id="content1", and change the inline opacity to 1, you will see the modal. jQuery's animate function is supposed to do this, but it does not.

This is only happening in IE 10.

Through my research of this I have found two theories: 1. It's a bug with IE10. or 2. jQuery's syntax does not yet work with IE10 in this one aspect. But, I haven't really been able to confirm either.

What is the best way to fix this, so that when the issue is fixed in IE or jQuery, it won't break it again?

UPDATE: I'm using jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: What version of jquery? can you produce a snippet of code that will help us recreate your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that updating the jQuery would have fixed this, as @ckozl proposed, but that seemed too risky, so I added this to the section of code after the modal loaded, and it worked:

> $("#content1").css("opacity","1").css("display","block");

Still not sure about the root of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you stripped the version of jQuery off your site... but my guess is update jQuery to the latest version, or update whatever UI type plugin you're using, it's most likely ignoring IE due to UA sniffing (or at least that's all i can assume)

i found it in the comments

```
/* jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
```

this version was released: November 21, 2011

Comment: I'm a little hesitant to update the jQuery for fear that it might mess up some other aspects of the site. Is that something I should be concerned with, or will the transition be unnoticeable?

Comment: the version you have is a little on the old side... i would say try it, see if it fixes your issue then cross the backwards compatibility issues when you get to them.  though all-in-all jQuery transitions are never that bad, might be some small code changes, but they are all documented in the change logs you could troll through: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/21/jquery-1-7-1-released/  or just give it the good old once over, jQuery makes a conscience effort not to break things...